# How to define a custom security with multiple api keys in fastapi?

Tags: fastapi

This is my plan,  but it can't be generated to the OpenAPI doc's Authentication section.

```
class HMACModel(BaseModel):
    api_key: APIKey = APIKey(**{"in": APIKeyIn.header}, name='Api-Key')
    signature: APIKey = APIKey(**{"in": APIKeyIn.header}, name='Signature')


class HMACAuth(APIKeyBase):
    model = HMACModel()
    scheme_name = 'HMACAuth'

    async def __call__(self, request: Request):
        api_key = request.headers.get('Api-Key')
        signature = request.headers.get('Signature')
        print(f's:{signature}, k:{api_key}')
        do_some_check()
        return api_key

@app.get('/')
async def test_api(req: ReqModel, api_key=Depends(HMACAuth())):
        pass
```

It seems that custom model will be ignore when the OpenAPI object init with analysis output `OpenAPI(**output)`.(There are security shema in output, but missd in OpenAPI object).

(Refer code :https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/d60dd1b60e0acd0afcd5688e5759f450b6e7340c/fastapi/openapi/utils.py#L372)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, getting OpenAPI and multi-api-key dependencies to play nicely seems to be an outstanding problem as seen in this [issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2835).

There are a few ways to handle it, the most straightforward of which is creating two `APIKeyHeader` dependencies and using them both in each request. You don't actually need to do any inheriting from the `APIKeyBase` class, as the `APIKeyHeader` class that FastAPI provides should do the trick on its own.

I would also probably define an additional dependency that uses the other two as sub-dependencies like so:

```py
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Security, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security.api_key import APIKeyHeader


app = FastAPI()


class HMACAuth:
    async def __call__(
        self,
        x_hmac_api_key: str = Depends(APIKeyHeader(name="x-hmac-api-key", scheme_name="HMACApiKey")),
        x_hmac_signature: str = Depends(APIKeyHeader(name="x-hmac-signature", scheme_name="HMACSignature")),
    ) -> Optional[str]:
        if x_hmac_api_key and x_hmac_signature:
            # do whatever check is needed here
            if x_hmac_api_key in ["valid-api-key"] and x_hmac_signature in ["valid-signature"]:
                return x_hmac_api_key

        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
            detail="Not authenticated",
        )


@app.get(
    "/", 
    response_model=str, 
    name="app:test-api",
    dependencies=[Security(HMACAuth())],
)
async def test_api() -> str:
     return "success"
```

You would then need to override your app's `openapi` method as explained in the [extending OpenAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#override-the-method) section of the docs.

The reason being that any route with this dependency would have different OpenAPI security schema generated for each sub-dependency. Meaning users would be able to enter in a value for either on in the OpenAPI docs and be "authenticated".

To remedy that, you could do something like this:

```py
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi


# ...previous code


def merge_hmac_securities(list_of_securities: List[Dict[str, List]]) -> List[dict]:
    """
    Find HMACApiKey and HMACSignature securities and merge them
    """
    original_securities = []
    hmac_security = {}
    for security in list_of_securities:
        if "HMACApiKey" in security or "HMACSignature" in security:
            hmac_security.update(security)
        else:
            original_securities.append(security)

    return original_securities + ([hmac_security] if hmac_security else [])


def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema

    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="Custom title",
        version="3.0.0",
        description="This is a very custom OpenAPI schema",
        routes=app.routes,
    )

    for path in openapi_schema.get("paths"):
        for http_method in openapi_schema["paths"][path]:
            list_of_securities = openapi_schema["paths"][path][http_method].get("security")
            if list_of_securities:
                merged_list_of_securities = merge_hmac_securities(list_of_securities)
                openapi_schema["paths"][path][http_method]["security"] = merged_list_of_securities

    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema

    return app.openapi_schema


app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

Doing that should solve both of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to specify different `scheme_name` for each ApiKey header, otherwise they will collide and probably one will overwrite the other in [OpenAPI schema](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/)

```
from fastapi.security import APIKeyHeader

api_key = APIKeyHeader(name='Api-Key', scheme_name='api-key')
signature = APIKeyHeader(name='Signature', scheme_name='signature')
```

Comment: Thank u very much